# IIS 7.5 site won't load - just spins in browser

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

I'm not well versed in IIS, and was just handed administration on a server in our environment.  One particulate subsite of the default site won't load for any users.

Windows 2008 r2

IIS 7.5.7600.16385

I can load up the console and other sites fine.  This site is supposed to serve files, but instead serves up a spinning loading icon for all of eternity.

Any help on how to track this issue down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... Which version of IIS, exactly?

Comment: IIS 7.5.7600.16385